# iphone 5 and storyboard setting autoresizing masks

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard, autoresize

I've got a storyboard-driven application, and I'm trying to modify it to support the iPhone 5.

There is a navigation controller, and then my `menuViewController`. In `viewDidLoad` of the menu controller, I have verified that self.view.frame is `{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}`. The view controller's size is set to "Inferred" in the Simulated Metrics, and the main view has "Autoresize Subviews" checked.

But my subviews are not getting resized! (Note that I can manually resize them in code, that's not a problem, but I would really like this to "work" using mostly IB, since I have a lot of views, and that would be about a million times easier.)

I have a full-screen subview that doesn't get resized. It's mask has basically everything enabled.

I also have subviews that are supposed to float at either the bottom or the top, and the ones that float at the top work, but the ones that are supposed to float at the bottom don't.

What should I be checking here? It's probably something stupid that i'm missing, but I've been scratching my head for an hour, and am getting close to just changing all my frames in code. (Which would be ugly as well as inelegant.)

Thanks!

Comment: "But my subviews are not getting resized!" : what do you mean? when rotating the device? or between an iPhone 4 and 5?

Comment: Between an iPhone 4 and iPhone 5.

Comment: I also tried calling `layoutSubviews` on `self.view` in `viewDidLoad`, nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a hint here: [How to resize App for Iphone 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697870/how-to-resize-app-for-iphone-5?rq=1)

Essentially one of the answers there suggests editing the xml of the storyboard directly. I went in and looked, and the top level view in my `viewController` had `autoresizesSubviews="NO"` I changed it to `YES`, and that fixed the problem for me.

As stated in my original post, I absolutely know for sure that checkbox was checked in the inspector pane. I have no idea why the xml didn't match the inspector.

Comment: I found this to be the case too. No amount of checking the Autoresize Subviews checkbox seemed to help. Going in xml of storyboard and saving that got the resizing to work. Thanks for this!

Comment: I added a subview programatically to a view container in a storyboard. I left everything as autoresizesSubviews="YES", except the view container.

Answer (score 1):

Check the springs in the autoresize control for your view (not the view controller) within the metrics pane. Try and make them like in the picture below.

[image]

Notice that you will not be able to set the internal springs for a top-level view object (but that's fine: just ensure the 4 side ticks are all activated).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what they look like, for both the view Controller's view property, as well as the subview that I am trying to have resize. Well, I guess the main view doesn't have width stretching enabled. But otherwise it's the same.